# "Missing Required Options" warning message not displayed for missing options

Tags: picocli

I am implementing picocli in my groovy script that takes couple of **Required Options** and couple of **Optional Options**.

When I run my script without passing any commandline argument **(** i.e. just **groovy my-script.groovy** **)** , it displays warning message  **"Missing Required Options"** for the Options marked with **"required = true"** which is expected and hence fine.

But when I pass in just the **Optional Option** without providing any parameter **(**i.e. just** --middle-name)** and also without any of the Required Options then I get the warning message **"Missing required parameter for option"** but no warning for the missing "Required Options" is diplayed.

**E.g.:**

Lets say,

Required options (**required=true**) : **--first-name** and **--last-name**

Optional option(**required=false**) : **--middle-name**

**Scenario 1:**

**groovy *my-script.groovy***

```
Missing required options: '--first-name=firstName', '--last-name=lastName'
```

**Scenario 2:**

**groovy *my-script.groovy* *--middle-name***

```
Missing required parameter for option '--middle-name' (middleName)
```

In the case of Scenario 2 I would also expect the `Missing required options: '--first-name=firstName', '--last-name=lastName'`

What could be the causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picocli parser does not try to find all errors, it simply stops as soon as a problem is found.

Since the optional option `--middle-name` was specified, but *without an option parameter*, the picocli parser shows an error message that this option requires a value.

If you were to specify a value for the `--middle-name` option, like this:

```
groovy my-script.groovy --middle-name=john
```

picocli would then show an error message for the next problem it encounters: `Missing required options: '--first-name=firstName', '--last-name=lastName'`

Comment: First and foremost I have to admit that Picocli is just awesome and there is nothing like that out there and thank you so much for this wonderful gift. But going through your comment gives me a feeling that this area can probably be enhanced. I might be wrong if there are some hard stops. Ideally a user would expect the commandline to guide them correctly with ease. This limitation makes it more of a trial and error process for the user if the cli is configured with multiple optional options. I understand the usage help can guide but showing an incomplete warning msg can be misleading too.

Comment: Is there a workaround to it or probably another approach that you would like to recommend.

Comment: Once the parser encounters a problem, it becomes difficult to make sense of the remaining arguments. So that is why the default behavior is the way it currently is: stop at first error.

However, you can experiment with a different mode, where picocli collects all errors:

ParserSpec.collectErrors(true)

This will require you to deal with the errors in the application, and loop over the collected errors and show error messages for them.

The collected errors can be obtained from ParseResult.errors()

The ParseResult can be obtained from CommandLine.getParseResult()

Good luck! 